# Reusable action Yii2, failed load form view

Tags: php, yii2

I want to create a reusable action inside a controller.
Yii2 usually creates the following views:

```
 update -> render form
 create -> render form
```

The problem is, I failed to load this `form`.

Yii2 throw an error `Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on string`

Here is the list of My apps directory.

- modules

  - finance

    - actions
      - BuatPengeluaranDiBukuBankAction.php
    - controllers
      - BukuBankController.php
    - views
      - buku-bank

      ```
           * create-pengeluaran-by-kasbon.php
           * _form-pengeluaran-by-kasbon
      ```

I will describe the following code.

### BuatPengeluaranDiBukuBankAction.php

```
class BuatPengeluaranDiBukuBankAction extends Action {

    public $modelClass;
    public $modelsDetailClass;

    public function run() {

        $request = Yii::$app->request;

        if($this->modelClass->load($request->post)){
           ... save here & redirect
        }
        
        ### Calling view 
        return $this->controller->render('create-pengeluaran-by-kasbon', [
           'model' => $this->modelClass,
           'modelsDetail' => empty($this->modelsDetailClass) ? [new BukuBankDetail()] : $this->modelsDetailClass,
        ]);
    }
}
```

### BukuBankController.php

```
class BukuBankController extends Controller {

    public function actions() {
        return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::actions(),[
            'create-pengeluaran-by-kasbon' => [
                'class' => BuatPengeluaranDiBukuBankAction::class,
                'modelClass' => BukuBank::class,
                'modelsDetailClass' => BukuBankDetail::class
            ]
        ]);

    }
}
```

### create-pengeluaran-by-kasbon.php

```
<div class="buku-bank-create-by-kasbon">
    <?php echo $this->render('_form-pengeluaran-by-kasbon', [ # Failed to load
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsDetail' => $modelsDetail,
    ]) ?>
</div>
```

### _form-pengeluaran-by-kasbon

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'dynamic-form',
        /*'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
        'formConfig' => ['labelSpan' => 3, 'deviceSize' => ActiveForm::SIZE_SMALL]*/
    ]); ?>

   .... lot of field here

 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you initialised the model class?

Comment: $model = Yii::createObject($this->modelClass);

Comment: You're passing the class name as a string to the view. Unless you've done `$this->modelClass = Yii::createObject($this->modelClass);`

Answer (score 0):

What is happening

```
'modelClass' => BukuBank::class,
'modelsDetailClass' => BukuBankDetail::class
```

are passed as strings and not objects to your action class so before use you need to instantiate (create) this models (objects) see code below with comments.

```
class BuatPengeluaranDiBukuBankAction extends Action {

    public $modelClass;
    public $modelsDetailClass;

    public function run() {

        $request = Yii::$app->request;

         // create instances of models here
        $model = Yii::createObject($this->modelClass);
        $modelsDetails = Yii::createObject($this->modelsDetailClass);


        // now you can use models
        if($model->load($request->post)){
            ... save here & redirect
        }
    
        ### Calling view 
        return $this->controller->render('create-pengeluaran-by-kasbon', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelsDetail' => $modelsDetails,
        ]);
    }
}
```